# what is matlab function is taking as sign of second order IIR filter?

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response

I am getting confused from the implementation regarding matlab function `filter([b0,b1,b2],[a1,a2],x)` and other function similar as `freqz`. I do not understand which sign I must put in `a` coefficients, since there is two different way of writing the transfer function for the same second order filter as you see on the these pic below
 [image]

when for example the `besself` function generate the coefficients, does it generate them as I write them $H(z)$ or I must write $1-a_0z^{-1}-a_2z^{-2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your source us using a pretty unusual convention. Most books or courses use the "+" sign in the denominator and that's the convention Matlab follows. See for example https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Z_Transform_Difference_Equations.html

The reason for that is simple: This way zeros are roots of the numerator polynomial and the poles are the roots of the denominator polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

The `filter` function assumes this form (for your case):

$$
\tilde{H}(z) = \frac{b_0+b_1z^{-1}+b_2z^{-2}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}
$$

where the $1$ on the bottom is from the assumption that $a_0=1$, and call it $\tilde{H}(z)$ so not to be confused with your $H(z)$. Since you have written the denominator with the signs of $a_1$ and $a_2$ inverted, then you just have to fix that before using `filter`.

Suppose someone wrote the transfer function from your question down $\big(H(z)\big)$, handed you the coefficients, and said use MATLAB to find the output. The only thing you need to do before is to invert $a_1$ and $a_2$: 
`filter(..., [a0, -a1, -a2], ...)`.

When using `besself`, it returns the coefficients in the form according to the transfer function $\tilde{H}(z)$, and you can then directly use those coefficients.

Comment: vWhen using besself, it returns the coefficients in the form according to the transfer function H~(z), and you can then directly use those coefficients. so you mean if I use freqz of the b,a provided by besself, I will get the bode of the transfer function. because I have seen that using bode(tf(b,a)) wontgive me same result

Comment: @Yaakov ```freqz``` is for the z-domain, ```bode``` is for the s-domain. There is also ```freqs``` which is the s-domain version and should match whatever you get on your bode plot